# Wordpress Jetpack video hosting

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, jetpack

Hope someone can help me.

I have purchases Jetpack for wordpress which includes the video hosting package. On my the site im currently building i want to have the ability to display a video at the top of a post but not actually in the post. From what i can see so far if i want to upload my own video to wordpress using jetpack i can only display it within a post by adding to the media. The effect i really want to get though is the video not in the post but within an ACF PRO custom field, mainly a 'gallery' as this needs to display at the top of the post when a user clicks onto the post. Everything i have tried so far hasnt worked and i really need a work around for it. Is there a way to get the shortcode from the video into a gallery?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

better way for add video to website is use video player frameworks like [plyr.io](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) and [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) and fluid player and more

You do not need another solution With these, put the videos at the top of your pages